# Android regular expression that split into Array of string

Tags: java, android, regex

I want a regular expression that matches as following

> String myString = 
>   "11 22 **01 02** *22 11*
>   11 22 **31 32** *22 11*
>   11 22 **51 42** *22 11* ......"

i want to match both starting **11 22** and ending string **22 11** sequence and also i want to split the string into array of 01 02,31 32,51 42, ....

```
String[] resultArray = myString.split("11 22 .* 22 11");
```

I am getting only empty array with proper size of **11 22** xxx **22 11** sequence.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: i don't know much about regex ..its very confusing for me ..so only i asked here.i used inbuild email regex and all .. but this is **custom Regex**

Comment: You've changed your question. It is unclear now.. what will be `some_text_1,some_text_2` in `11 22 01 02 22 11`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) for that purpose.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("MY TEXT (.*) MY TEXT MY TEXT (.*) My TEXT");
Matcher m = p.matcher("MY TEXT hello you MY TEXT MY TEXT are here My TEXT");
if (m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group(1));  // prints 'hello you'
     System.out.println(m.group(2));  // prints 'are here'
}
```

Comment: +1 i have made this correct. but i want an expression only for split but this m.find also looks good.